# Fourier (Hankel?) transform of a discrete set of radial points (question from a chemist!)

Tags: statistics, fourier-analysis, numerical-methods, physics, chemistry

I'm sorry because I'm not a mathematician so that my question may look a little bit messy.

I have tabulated values [1] of a 3 dimensional radial function $f(r)$:
  $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2})=f(r)$

I'd like to Fourier transform it in order to get $f(k)$ (or when having $f(k)$ transforming it to $f(r)$. I have looked around and understood this is a Hankel transform of order? (2 or 3, did not get it). And I did not find a practical way of doing this transformation. I have access to web, fortran and mathematica 7.

Could you please, please, please help me?

[1] To be more practical: I have a picture where is plotted the static structure factor $S(k)$ of a inhomogeneous fluid as obtained by neutron diffraction. I can extract points $(k:S(k))$ from this picture. $S(k)$ is related to the direct correlation function $C(k)$ as defined by Ornstein-Zernike through $S(k)=(1-nC(k))^{-1}$ where $n$ is a constant. I'd like to plot $C(r)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I found the result here:
[casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/FFTLog/app.ps.gz](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/FFTLog/app.ps.gz)
and it has been confirmed by someone else. Your formulae is not exactly true while I am not able to demonstrate it :(. The formulae for a **3 dimensional sphericaly symetric function $f$** are: $ f(k)=\int_0^{\infty} f(r)\dfrac{\sin(kr)}{kr}4\pi r^2dr$ and $ f(r)=\int_0^{\infty} f(k)\dfrac{sin(kr)}{kr} \dfrac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3} k^2 dk$

Comment: Two things: (a) you should probably post comments as comments, and not as answers. (b) What Alice wrote and what you wrote are exactly the same. Perhaps you are not familiar with the [unnormalised sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radial symmetric Fourier transforms in 2 D are Hankel transforms.
Spherically symmetric ones in 3D I think give you something like

$$ f(k) = 4 \pi \int f(r)  {\rm sinc}(kr) ~ r^2 dr $$

To show this you need to do the integral of 
$$f(k) = 2\pi \int \int f(r) e^{i kr\cos \theta} \sin \theta d \theta r^2 dr $$

Which follows from
$$ f(k,\theta', \phi') = \int \int \int  e^{i {\bf k \cdot r}} f(r,\theta,\phi) r^2 dr \sin \theta d\theta d\phi $$
and ${\bf k \cdot r} = k r (\cos \theta \cos \theta' + \sin \theta \sin \theta' \cos(\phi -\phi')) $.

Comment: At first sight I misunderstood your answer because I'm not familiar with the unnormalized sinc function (thanks @Willie-Wong for the link).

But your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much @Alice!